# How to turn off professionalfonts for a specific variable.?

Tags: beamer, fonts, sans-serif

in Latex I usually use

```
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
```

for calligraphic text.

But sometimes I need calligraphic text and normal text mixed. Once I use `professionalfonts` all the text in the mathmode automatically converted to calligraphic text. So how to mix them together like shown in the image.

All the text are calligraphic :

[image]

Calligraphic and normal text mixed :

[image]

Comment: By "calligraphic", do you mean a serif font, and by "normal" text, to you mean a sans-serif font?

Comment: Have you tried `$p(y | \mathsf{x})$`?

Comment: @mico I haven't and it works. Thanks for the solution. Why didn't you write this as a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it that by "calligraphic font" you mean a serif font and that by "normal font" you mean a sans-serif font. If that's the case, simply use `\mathsf{...}` to write some variables using the sans-serif font face. E.g.,

```
$p(y | \mathsf{x})$
```

Better still, write `$p(\, y \mid \mathsf{x} \,)$`, for a less-cramped look.

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\begin{document}
$p(y|x)$, $p(y|\mathsf{x})$, $p(\,y\mid\mathsf{x}\,)$
\end{document}
```